# Вид придаточного

Tags: синтаксис

"Белый шар под потолком сиял до того, что резало глаза" - это изъяснительное придаточное или следствия?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение с грамматической ошибкой. По смыслу скорее придаточное степени. И лучше "сиял так ярко,что резало глаза". Вообще, многозначными бывают не только слова, но и члены предложения, и придаточные. Значение следствия здесь присутствует.  Но тогда я бы исправила так: "...сиял ярко, так что резало глаза".